# How to add concatenation to transfer learning?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning, semantic-segmentation

I'm using transfer learning for semantic segmentation.

```py
model=vgg(weights="imagenet")
new_model=Sequential()
for l,n in model.layers:
     new_model.add(l)
     if(n==18): break

 #Upsampling
m1=model.layers[-1].output
new_model.add(Conv2DTranspose(512,(3,3),strides=(2,2), 
padding="same"))
m2=new_model.layers[-1].output
concatenate1=concatenate(m1,m2)
```

Till this step it works fine. Now how can I add this concatenation to the network.

```py
new_model.layers[-1].output=concatenate1.output 
new_model.layers[-1].output=concatenate1
# these are wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the [functional version](https://jovianlin.io/keras-models-sequential-vs-functional/) of keras that will be easier for you.

You will simply use all the layers to n = 18 and that output will connect to m1.

Finally, you create the model. The code would be the following:

```py
model = vgg(weights="imagenet")
input_ = model.input
for l, n in model.layers:
    if n == 18: 
        last_layer = l
        break

#Upsampling
m1 = last_layer
m2 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(m1)
concatenate1 = Concatenate(axis=-1)(m1, m2)

new_model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=concatenate1)
```